# Passing CSS classes into sanity block-content root

Tags: gatsby, sanity

Imagine following situation:

I retrieve rich text as block-content from sanity CMS. The block-content contains a single block, which could be for example `<h2>Hello World</h2>`. This HTML is the result of `<Blockcontent block={someBlockContent}/>` using **@sanity/block-content-to-react**.

My Question:

Is there a way to pass a CSS-class into that rendered H2 element? So it would render like `<h2 class="title">Hello World</h2>`? I saw the attributes **className** and **renderContainerOnSingleChild**, but those would add a parent to this H2 Element. But I want to add a CSS class without adding a parent DOM.

Thank You!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a list of overrides to the `serializers` prop. For something like an H2, which would be part of the `block` type in the array, you would do this:

```
import BlockContent from "@sanity/block-content-to-react"

const overrides = {
  h2: props => <h2 className="title" {...props} />,
}

const serializers = {
  types: {
    block: props =>
      // Check if we have an override for the “style”
      overrides[props.node.style] 
        // if so, call the function and pass in the children, ignoring
        // the other unnecessary props
        ? overrides[props.node.style]({ children: props.children })

        // otherwise, fallback to the provided default with all props
        : BlockContent.defaultSerializers.types.block(props),
  }
}

const SomeComponent = () => 
  <BlockContent blocks={...} serializers={serializers} />
```

---

Edit: Since answering this I've authored and released a library called [react-portable-text](https://github.com/coreyward/react-portable-text) to make working with Sanity's block content in React easier. Here's the above using `react-portable-text` instead:

```
import PortableText from "react-portable-text"

const SomeComponent () => 
  <PortableText content={blockContent} serializers={{ h2: Heading }} />

const Heading = ({ children }) => 
  <h2 className="title">{children}</h2>
```

Comment: I want to dynamically add classes, not like this. I want to call from some other component like `<SomeComponent blocks={...} classes="class1 class2" />`. It should not matter if it is a H2 or a paragraph.

Comment: @MucoBey That's fine, you can do that with the approach I've outlined, just use `React.createElement(props.node.style, { ...props, className: "class1 class2" })` instead of an overrides declaration. You can also define that with a variable, nothing Sanity or Gatsby specific about it.